# How to verify that mock object was "gotten"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Is there a way to assert that my mocked object was "gotten" ?

```
public class Car
{
    private readonly IValidationDict _validationDict;
    public Car(IValidationDict validationDict)
    {
        _validationDict = validationDict;
    }

    public void Go()
    {
       var myValidation = _validationDict;   //I would like to assert that _validationDict was indeed assigned to another variable or "gotten"
    }
}
```

In my unit test I would have something like:

```
var mock = new Mock<IValidationDict>();
var sut = new Car(IValidationDict.Object);
```

**Is there a way to assert that my mocked object was "gotten" ?**

Comment: What happens to `myValidation` in the rest of the method? Presumably it invokes some member of the mock so you should be able to assert on that.

Comment: @Lee wouldnt that be kind of not classical unit testing, but depending on something else to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'depending on something else to work' but since `Go` is a void method you are only executing it for its side effects. Since you are providing a mock in your test, you are asserting those effects through expectations on the mock you provide. The details of how that happen within the `Go` method should be irrelevant to the test.

Comment: How about using Verify(), e.g. `mock.Verify(x => x.Go(), Times.Once);`? You would need to mock the object `Car`in this example.

Comment: @BryanWoodford Wouldn't you then be testing that the test called the method `Go` on the mock it created?

Comment: @LukeW - that's currently where `_validationDict` gets assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to verify that your mock object was used as part of the assignment.  The assignment of `myValidation` happens outside the bounds of the Moq framework and therefore Moq can't do any interception to track it.

As @Lee state, there is an assumption that `myValidation` is used somewhere else and the use of that variable (which will be a mocked instance) can be checked.

One alternative if you **must** know if your mock was accessed would be to create a factory class that has a method for obtaining your validation dictionary (something like `GetValidation`) and then pass a mocked factory to your `Car` and verify that the `GetValidation` method was called on the factory.